# Unable to pass an array as argument of a javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the quickSort algorithm in javascript, i have to extract 10,000 numbers from a txt file, pass them into an array, and pass this  as an argument of my quickSort function, using the fs module of nodejs. The code is able to read the 10,000 numbers, and to convert them from an array of string to an array of number, but when i try to pass the array into my function, only 3472 numbers are passed, which i don't understand.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Reading the data from the file containing the 10,000 numbers
const file = fs.readFileSync('./quickSort.txt', 'utf-8');

//Checking if it has read all the numbers correctly 
console.log(file); // Displays the 10,000 numbers as strings in an array

// Convert them from string to integer
const finalFile = file.split('\n').map(e => {
  return parseInt(e, 10);
 })

// Checking if it has converted each element of the array to an integer
//console.log(finalFile) displays the array, with the 10,000 elements converted to integers

// Initialize a counter for the comparaisons made by the quickSort algorithm
let comparisons = 0;

// Sort them using quick sort
function quick_Sort(origArray) {

  if (origArray.length <= 1) {
    return origArray;
  } else {
    // Checking if the array has been correctly passed as an argument 
    console.log(origArray.length); //Displays 3742 instead of 10,000
    var left = [];
    var right = [];
    var newArray = [];
    var pivot = origArray.pop();
    var length = origArray.length;
    // I have tried comparisons += length - 1; too, but i doesn't work
    comparisons += length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (origArray[i] <= pivot) {
        left.push(origArray[i]);

      } else {
        right.push(origArray[i]);
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
      comparisons++;
      if (right[i] < pivot) {
        return right.splice(i, 0, pivot);
      }
    }

    return newArray.concat(quick_Sort(left), quick_Sort(right));
  }
}

// Display the result
const result = quick_Sort(finalFile);

// expected output: 25
console.log(result);
```

Thank you very much.

Edit: In fact the problem of the size comes from the last for loop of the function, if i delete it, and insert the pivot between like that, it works (thanks to StardustGogeta) :

```js
return newArray.concat(quick_Sort(left), pivot, quick_Sort(right));
```

Comment: What is the error? Maybe there's a problem with execution time? Is it possible that it takes more than defined timeout?

Comment: Are you **absolutely** sure that finalFile has 10000 lines? I am unable to replicate this issue when using an array with the correct size. (Are you able to give us the file you are testing with?)

Comment: @StardustGogeta Hello, thank you for your help, i have posted the file here https://github.com/HugoDouma/quickSort.

Comment: @Kacper Hello, thank you for your help, i don't have any errors displaying when i play the code, i only have an input of 3742 numbers , because the length of originArray is only of 3742 numbers (i checked this using a console.log inside the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logical error. You need to change

```
return newArray.concat(quick_Sort(left), quick_Sort(right));
```

to

```
return newArray.concat(quick_Sort(left), pivot, quick_Sort(right));
```

With that change, the program works for me. The problem is that you are accidentally getting rid of (via `.pop()`) approximately 1/3 of your input values  (the `pivot` values) during sorting.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const finalFile = file.split('\r?\n').map(.....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parsing code works for me except for one issue: `parseInt` returns `NaN` for the last new line so you need to remove the last element from the array like this: `finalFile.pop();`. However this does not explain why you are seeing such a difference in the number of elements. There must be something different either in the code or the file you posted.